# how to enable font ligatures in php GD library

Tags: php, laravel, image, imagettftext, ligature

greetings fellow programmers,
I'm making images from text, and I was ordered to make it support ligatures.
is it possible to do so?

I'm using imagettftext & imagettfbbox from GD library

Comment: If it's possible? Probably some how (most things are possible). It might not be supported out of the box though, so you need to do [some proper research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and see if you can find some examples or libraries that can help.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, I've searched and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Could you post a small example of the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

GD is only one library for image processing. PHP also has other library extensions:

[ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.

[Gmagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) a php extension to create, modify and obtain meta information of images using the GraphicsMagick API.

[Cairo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.cairo.php) a native PHP extension to create and modify graphics using the Cairo Graphics Library.

[Exif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) With the exif extension you are able to work with image meta data.

Here is comparison: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/comparision_of_php_image_libraries.html